# plugin css is not being applied to the page?

Tags: css

I have enqueue the styles in script using the following code.

```
function libload()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style_file' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'lib/plugin_styles.css' , array(), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('js_file',  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'lib/plugin_js.js', array(), null, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','libload');
```

The css file is loading correct style files as well. But the styles are not appearing in the firebug inspect elements nor being applied to the page.

The css is the basic one simply a test css.

```
.addtogunbtn
{
    color:red;
}
```

but not being applied,.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding different name in the id section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)'s 5th parameter is not boolean. Use following code:

```
function libload()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style_file' , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'lib/plugin_styles.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('js_file',  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'lib/plugin_js.js', array(), null, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','libload');
```

Comment: brother i have figure it out the problem was with file name,., thanks for your time any way

Comment: Glad you can fix the problem.