# plugin css is not being applied to the page

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I looked at this question:

[plugin css is not being applied to the page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253504/plugin-css-is-not-being-applied-to-the-page)

but I couldnt solve my problem.

I use below code like the question:

```
 <?php
                    function libload()
                    {
                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/bootstrap.min.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles' );

                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles2',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/style.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles2' );

                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles3',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/responsive.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles3' );

                    }
                    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','libload');
                  ?>
```

style files are loading as you can see below link but wp not apply them:

http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/sample-page/

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: No, the style files are not loading. If you view your source, those files aren't listed. What file is your code running in? Is the plugin active?

Comment: @WebElaine yes, plugin is active.I need all css files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change integratation code with this:

```
  <?php
                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/bootstrap.min.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles' );

                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles2',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/style.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles2' );

                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles3',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/responsive.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles3' );
                  ?>
```

Comment: this could cause you problems down the line. You are just skipping over using the correct action hook with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but the page you linked to doesn't seem to have them included.

This means that this line is not being run:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','libload');
```

Check if the php file that you have it inside of is included by one of your plugin files?

Or that you are trying to include a file with the wrong path.

Check that the file is in a plugin not a theme folder, or you will need a different path.

Comment: I solved it like this :

  <?php
                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/bootstrap.min.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles' );

                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles2',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/style.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles2' );

                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles3',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/responsive.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles3' );
                  ?>